# Math Expression to lambda function

Tags: python, sympy

I have to make a equation solver, and for that I need input from user, and the user provides input as string, which cannot be solved using eval since that expression/equation contain a variable **x**. All I need to do is that convert that equation given as string into a lambda function.

Example

```
>>> lambda_func = parser('2x+x')
>>> lambda_func(2)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> input = '2*x+x'
>>> lambda_func = lambda x: eval(input)
>>> lambda_func(2)
6
>>> input = '3+x'
>>> lambda_func(1)
4
```

Comment: Ehhhhhh, relying on the fact that the lambda parameter is the same name as the input expression gives of a huge code smell

Comment: I mean yeah. But that's what the question was.

Comment: The "sympy" tag gives a hint as to what libraries you could use

Comment: How has this turned into homework for _me_?

Comment: @isaactfa It's a property of biology, if you study child education during the emergence of learning.  Every single child without fail learns to command others to produce education as the first request for configuration.  This is where the stackoverflow community has to gently remind them that this is an earned indulgence and they need to evolve how to educate self by giving education and auto self-tuning.  40% of all deleted artifacts from the low quality review queue are from this anomaly.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions